# Is it possible to calculate and display volume of a mesh object?

Tags: mesh, measurement

How can I display volume of any mesh object?

I can display length of an edge, the area of the face, but nothing for volume. Is it possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the [3D Print Toolbox](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/3d_print_toolbox.html) add-on for that. Activate it in the *Preferences* and it will appear in the Tool Shelf of the 3D View. Top line buttons let you calculate volume and total area.

[image: 3D Print View]

Comment: For me, the addon was called `3D Print Toolbox` and you open it on the absolute left - there are vertical "tabs" Tools, Create, ...., `3D Print Toolbox` (look below "File" menu)

Comment: How does this work in Blender 2.8? I don't see the menu.

Comment: Print3D add-on crashes blender in Ubuntu 20.04 (v2.28.7) but works if using v2.93.2

Answer (score 10):

First activate the *3D-Print Toolbox* addon: *Edit > Preference >Add-ons* and search 'print'.
Now you can find the toolbox in the sidebar panel (press n if it does not show)
Look in the 3D-print tab under statistics.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an addon for this.

In general, the methods for calculating the volume of a mesh can be divided into two categories: (1) **Analytical methods** which are based on mathematical formulas, these methods are efficient and accurate but are limited to simple shapes. (2) [Numerical methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_method) which involve breaking the mesh into smaller parts and summing the volume of those parts. These methods can be applied to any shape, but the accuracy of the results may vary depending on the number of parts used and the method for calculating the volume of each part.

Here's a script that uses the *Numerical Method* to calculate the volume of a mesh.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

obj = bpy.context.active_object
me = obj.data

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)
bm.transform(obj.matrix_world)
bmesh.ops.triangulate(bm, faces=bm.faces)

volume = 0
for f in bm.faces:
    v1 = f.verts[0].co
    v2 = f.verts[1].co
    v3 = f.verts[2].co
    volume += v1.dot(v2.cross(v3)) / 6

print("Volume:", volume)

bm.free()
```

Comment: This can also calculate the total volume of multiple separate meshes within an object, but take note that mesh overlapping is not taken into consideration and will still result in the sum of all mesh volumes regardless.

Comment: Very nice. I use this to find duplicate meshes with flipped normals and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

For performance reasons I came up with the following solution based on rigid body ops.

```
def select_object(ob):
    for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        o.select_set(False)
    ob.select_set(True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob

def calc_object_volume(ob):
    select_object(ob)
    bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add()
    bpy.ops.rigidbody.mass_calculate(material='Custom', density=1) # density in kg/m^3
    return ob.rigid_body.mass
```