# How to calculate weight and model

Tags: modeling

On the given specification i have model. The specification is given for 1 model. I have to model total 6 size with the cast iron material.

**Model on given specification**

[image]

They need 5, 8, 12, 16, 20 & 24 kg size. Now im confuse the given specification is which size and how to model the various 6 size. How it will work. Can u plz explain now can i model this 5, 8, 12, 16, 20 & 24 kg size.

Comment: You can get the volume of your object (make sure it is manifold) https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/63113/86891 and use the material density https://www.google.com/search?q=cast+iron+density to get the resulting mass. You have to make sure your specification doesn't state the model should be hollow though or you will have to accomodate for that

Comment: @Gorgious is 10.7cm for 5kg a sphere is the correct calculation