# How to calculate volume of a mesh object

Tags: 3d-printing, rigidbody

With the 3D print addon. Under Rigid Body -> Mass i have put the value of 5Kg. And Under object -> Rigid Body -> Calculate mass with a custom i have change value to 7200 (cast iron) as density given. Click on the value it suddenly change to 44.5kg. And i want 5Kg. How it works. Any suggestion whats going wrong, or help. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a maths problem ? 6,172 [dm3] * 7,2 [kg / dm3] = 44,4 [kg] : ie scale your object by 1/8,9 times (44,5 / 5)

Comment: @Gorgious if i scale all the measurement will go wrong

Comment: The title seems misleading. But for anyone who came here to find the answers for calculating the volume of a mesh look no further :) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63113/is-it-possible-to-display-volume-of-a-mesh-object/283612#283612