3D print toolbox volume result
I want to calculate the volume of a model.
I believe the volume should be the same as the area since I have extruded the face with 1m but it shows a different value.
I suspect it is because it consists of loose parts. I hope the addon is able to still calculate the volume, it does it right with the area calculation.
If so, does anybody know how I can still generate a good volume calculation with the addon when an object has loose parts?




A cube with 2 m on each axis has a volume of 2 m · 2 m · 2 m = (2 m)³ = 8 m³. The screenshot says 8.0 m³, so what exactly is wrong there?

Is your scale applied? See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous

Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63113/is-it-possible-to-calculate-and-display-volume-of-a-mesh-object

Thank you for your response and sorry for my late reply, I was on vacation. I have now attached the file.
As you will see the base area is 6608m². however the volume result after extruding it 1 meter in the z axis is 1421m³. The scale is applied.
